# Integrating WP-TLC-Transients with Wordpress - Where to Begin?

Tags: transient

Last week, I [asked about creating transients](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113970/is-priming-a-transient-cache-possible) that would update before expiry to prevent users from waiting for the long loading time. I was pointed to  [WP-TLC-Transients](https://github.com/markjaquith/WP-TLC-Transients) which sound like exactly what I need, but unfortunately, I am at a loss with where to begin.

Here are the associated files:

- class-tlc-transient-update-server.php
- class-tlc-transient.php
- functions.php
- tlc-transients.php

Hopefully this is not too basic a question, but I'm interested in where to place the associated files to even begin trying to work with the code.

EDIT:

I placed `class-tlc-transients-update-server.php`, `class-tlc-transient.php`, and `tlc-transients.php` to my theme's directory and added `include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/tlc-transients.php' );` to my `functions.php`

With that settled, I plan on following the example in the readme. Are tlc-transients saved in the same place at wordpress transients? I'm wondering how I can best check if my implementation is successful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

1. Place wherever your code can access
2. Include `tlc-transients.php` during your plugin/theme load (or otherwise before `init` hook)
3. Follow examples from readme for library's API use

PS in [still not very common] case you are using Composer you can also just require [`markjaquith/wp-tlc-transients`](https://packagist.org/packages/markjaquith/wp-tlc-transients) in `composer.json`.

Comment: after "[still not very common]" I'd added "among WP developers" in PHP world, outside Wordpress, Composer is now very popular... :)

Comment: @G.M. yeah, that was implied :)